# change the text of the label

Tags: javascript, html

change the text of label to "hand" when the pointer become hand and hover on the box and then change the text back to "arrow" ... here is my code

```html
<html>
<style>
  #box:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }
  #box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: black;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="box" onmouseover="myFunction()"></div>
  <label id="lab">arrow</label>
</body>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = "hand";
    document.getElementById("box").style.cursor = "pointer"
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `onmouseout` to trigger function for mouseout.

```css
#box:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onmouseover="myFunction(true)" onmouseout="myFunction(false)"></div>
<label id="lab">arrow</label>
<script>
  function myFunction(over) {
    if (over) {
      document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = "hand";
      document.getElementById("box").style.cursor = "pointer"
    } else {
      document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = "arrow";
    }
  }
</script>
```